# Multi JPA transaction inner one method

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I've got an example which is need to rollback some method inner for loop by condition outer loop.
I using EntittyManager and @Transactional.
Because logic in loop is complexity, so i don't want to bring into 2 loop.
How do I can implement the rollback, commit ?

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implement StudentService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean execute(List<ADto> adtoList) {
      boolean a = true;
      for(ADto dto : adtoList) {
          boolean a =  method1(dto); // call to sub method2, method3 to insert data into A, B table
          if(a == false) {
             break;
          }
          method4(); // do insert data into D, E table
          method5(); // do update into F table

       }
    if(a == false) {
       // need rollback all inserted data in A, B table which is inserted in method1, method2, method3 (of all loop element)
       // still commit all inserted data at method4(), method5()  (of all loop element)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the problem statement it appears that the

> method1(),method2() and method3() call should operate within the current txn.
>
> method4() and method5() should operate on their own separate txn(s).

When method1() returns false , the break executes and the RuntimeException would rollback whatever was inserted till that point through method1() transaction.

method4() and method5() data will be persisted as they are in independent transaction(s) of their own.

Read more on

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW = 3; If DataSourceTransactionObject T1 is
>   already started for Method M1 and it is in progress(executing method
>   M1) .If another method M2 start executing then T1 is suspended for the
>   duration of method M2 with new DataSourceTransactionObject T2 for
>   M2.M2 run within its own transaction context

Also note that a self invocation ( a method call within the target object ) will not lead to a transaction . You will need to do a self injection for transaction on method4() and method5() to work . Something as follows

```
         @Service @Transactional
            public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

               @Autowired
               private StudentService self;   //self injection ;

               @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
               public boolean execute(List<ADto> adtoList) {
                boolean a = true;
                for(ADto dto : adtoList) {
                  boolean a = method1(dto); // uses the current txn.
                  if(a == false) {
                      break;
                  }
                  self.method4(); // do insert data into D, E table
                  self.method5(); // do update into F table
                }
                if(!a) {
                  throw new RuntimeException("Rollback Txn for method1");
                }
               }


               @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
               public void method4() {

               }

               @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
               public void method5() {

               }
            }
```

method4() and method5() are annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` and invoked on the proxy

Also read about REQUIRES_NEW behavior from article https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-propagation-tutorial

Comment: thank, but there are some point as below :
1. "Also note that a self invocation ( a method call within the target object ) will not lead to a transaction . You will need to do a self injection for transaction on method1() to work"
=> Sorry but I wrong typing, not is "extends StudentService", correct is "implements StudentService". I've update again.

2. By your way,  where is method1(dto) called ? (note : this method to call the sub method2, method3 to insert data into A, B table.

Comment: That was a copy and paste issue. modified the code as per your comment

Comment: Thank, but I need that rollback data which are inserted at all previous elements of adtoList, not only for current element.

Comment: Modified the answer.

Comment: My problem is need to rollback at outer for by condition (ex: a == false), not only rollback when occur exception. So I think that your suggestion has not resolved my problem.
I intended to add 2 entity manager to control 2 transaction

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't help . You may throw a runtime exception of your choice instead of returning a boolean on a rollback condition from method1() . That should also serve the same purpose

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll find solution for my problem.
I don't want to throw a runtime exception, because in reallity business , I have to check a condition to rollback or not.

Comment: Modified the code once more. Not sure if this helps you , but the code logic and the propogation setup will work as per your requirement.